# How to resolve backward compatibility issues? WPF exe file is not opening in other PC

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio, exe, backwards-compatibility

I build WPF application on Window 10, .Netframwork 4.5. It's successfully working on my machine and when I tried to run exe file (bin/debug/app.exe) by another PC (window 8.1) it's not Working.. No error statement is showing, it's just loading but nothing happened..
My application contain LINQ to SQL (DB) and communication with some network over UDP..
What am I doing wrong? 
What and How compatibility issues are needed to resolve? 
What possible problems are occurring ?
Thanks

Comment: You have installed the .Net Framework 4.5 for your Win8.1 Machine?

Comment: Yes. It's present

Comment: Did you copied the whole folder content (not only the .exe)?

Comment: Yes, the Whole Folder

Comment: Take a screenshot of you SOLUTION > PROJECT > References folder and post it in your question. Most likely one of the references are not copied.

Comment: You need to implement logging in your application to be able to figure out what actually happens when it fails. If you don't know why it crashes, you won't be able to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

It's impossible to say without knowing what your application actually tries to do. As a first step, to simply diagnose the cause of the issue, you need to implement some kind of logging in your application. Once you see the exception message and the stack trace, you will hopefully be able to figure out how to fix the error.

But if you don't know *why* the application crashes, you won't ever be able to fix it.